# Clang++-6.0 with CMake does not recognize std::string_view

Tags: c++, cmake, gnu-make

I am using Clang++ 6.0, CMake 3.11.4, Make 4.1 on Linux. I am compiling from the terminal using my own CMakeLists.txt, which contains both `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` and 
`set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)`. However, I need to use `std::string_view` in my project, and for some reason, clang does not recognize it. I do include `<string>` as well. The error I get is:

`error: no type named 'string_view' in namespace 'std'`

Also, if i try to `#include <string_view>`, I get:

`fatal error: 'string_view' file not found`

What exactly am I missing? AFAIK, `string_view` is a part of the C++17 standard, and Clang supports C++17 since Clang 4, also I am using relatively new Make and CMake.

Comment: Have you verified the compiler version and the `-std` flag cmake generates by e.g. `make VERBOSE=1`? If yes, can you compile a dummy translation unit that does nothing but includes `<string_view>` by calling `clang++ -std=c++17 dummy.cpp`?

Comment: Have you tried this with CMake instead of `set`: `target_compile_features(project PUBLIC cxx_std_17)`?

Comment: are you sure cmake is using Clang ? Default is usually GCC on Linux.

Comment: Ok, so I tried running make with verbose on and 1. yes, it does use clang, but 2. it uses -std=gnu++1z.

Comment: Are you sure the standard library support C++17? It is also possible to use clang with non-c++17 standard library.

Comment: Also, @lubgr, I tried that and got this error:
`
dummy.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'string_view' file not found
`

Comment: @kubci98 Can you try `find / -type f -name 'string_view*' 2>/dev/null` and check whether it outputs anything?

Comment: @lubgr: `/usr/include/c++/5/experimental/string_view.tcc` and `/usr/include/c++/5/experimental/string_view`

Comment: clang libc++ support for `std::string_view` is marked as complete in the [documentation](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html) so it should not be in the experimental directory.

Comment: So what I should do is update libstdc++ on my system, am I right?

Comment: Is the path you are getting from your find command the path of the LLVM libc++ or the gnu libc++? I tried to do the same on my pc and I get `/usr/include/c++/8.1.1/experimental/string_view` and `/usr/include/c++/8.1.1/string_view` but there 8.1.1 refers to my gcc version, so I suspect the path you are finding is not the c++ standard library shipped with clang.

Comment: So maybe you are not using the LLVM libc++, it appears that you have to add the flag `-stdlib=libc++` to the clang++ CLI if you have the LLVM libc++ installed. [docs](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html)

Comment: We don' know what you're missing since you haven't shown us what (else) is in your `CMakeLists.txt` file.  Please do so, and also the command you are issuing from the command line to invoke `CMAKE`, if there's anything special about it.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I fixed the issue by installing gcc-8 and i kept clang using GNU headers.

Answer (score 0):

The more modern way of enforcing this requirement is:

```
target_compile_features(myTarget PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

This has better support for the capabilities of the compiler, if there's a compatibility issue, you're more likely to get cmake to report the problem.

You really need to confirm which version of clang is being used. You say you have clang 6. But you're getting `-std=gnu++1z` which is a strong sign cmake is using an older version.

You can set the compiler a number of ways, here's using the environment:

```
$ export CC=/usr/bin/clang
$ export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is Clang
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang
```

Answer (score -1):

If your compile complaints, you can replace **`std::string_view`** by **`std::string&`**

Comment: These types have very different performance characteristics, though